# Area inside the curve and the line x=0

Tags: coordinate-systems

> Find the area between the curve with equation $x+2|y|=1$
>   and the line $x=0$(y axis)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I found that the points at which x=0 are 1/2 and -1/2 .After that I really don't know how to proceed

Comment: If you've taken calculus, integrate.  If not, graph both curves and use what you know about the area of triangles.

Comment: I understood that I have to integrate but then with the equation $|y|=(1-x)/2$ I have no idea how to integrate an equation which has a modulus function

Comment: Oh. I'll try that method. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First graph both curves:

[image]

Then notice that these curves can be expressed as functions of $y$ but not functions of $x$.  So we write the two curves as $x=1-2|y|$ and $x=0$.  Then we integrate the difference of the two, so that we get the area between them, with respect to $y$:

$$\begin{align}\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \big[(1-2|y|)-(0)\big]\ dy &= \int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \big(1-2|y|\big)\ dy \\ &= \int_0^{1/2} (1-2y)\ dy + \int_{-1/2}^{0} \big(1-2(-y)\big)\ dy\end{align}$$

This should be pretty easy to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

See that the best thing is to draw the graph of that equation see that you will get a  triangle and you can calculate the area.

Also mention how far you have tried so that other potential user's can help you with answer and you will get better help.

[image]